# Fastest way to get an image from Skitch into OmniFocus?

Tags: graphics, omnifocus, skitch

What's the fastest way to get a screenshot from Skitch into OmniFocus?

When you drag and drop an image into OmniFocus, it only creates a link to the image, rather than embedding it. One way to do this is to drag and drop the image from Skitch to finder, and then from finder to OmniFocus by holding down the command key, but this is tedious, especially when I need to do it many times. Another way is to drop onto finder, and then right-click and choose to attach and embed in OmniFocus, but this too is time consuming.

Is there any way to drag the image directly from Skitch into OmniFocus and have the image be embedded in the task?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do it without AppleScript.

Here is my way to do this:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    try
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in added_items
            set this_item to item i of added_items
            tell application "Finder" to set file_name to (name of this_item)
            tell application "OmniFocus"
                tell quick entry
                    open
                    set NewTask to make new inbox task with properties {name:file_name}
                    tell the note of NewTask
                        make new file attachment with properties {file name:this_item, embedded:true}
                    end tell
                    activate
                end tell
            end tell
        end repeat
    end try
end adding folder items to
```

1. Save this AppleScript to `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/Add File To Omnifocus.scpt` You must use root access. ([Download script](http://cl.ly/3L3a391K1x0V2P0e3L2v))
2. Create a folder under your `Documets` folder
3. Right-click on this folder, and select Services>Folder Actions Setup
4. Select the "`Add File To Omnifocus`" script

Now you can drop any file to this folder(I keep it in my Dock) and it automatically create a QuickEntry Task with embedded attachment.

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Drag the image from Skitch directly to OmniFocus while holding Alt/Option key.

Comment: This does the same exact thing as a normal drag and drop.